# Youtube video adjustable size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

thanks for looking at this post,
I currently have the following home page :
[image: Current setup]

But when i resize it I get the following :
[image: issue i am facing]

The code i currently have is :

```java
import "../styles/SponsorUs.css";
import svg from "../assets/parcours.svg";
import YouTube, { YouTubeProps } from 'react-youtube';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function Example() {
    const onPlayerReady: YouTubeProps['onReady'] = (event) => {
        // access to player in all event handlers via event.target
        event.target.pauseVideo();
    }

    const opts: YouTubeProps['opts'] = {
        height: '350',
        width: '640',
        playerVars: {
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 2,
            rel : 0,
            mute : 1,
        },
    };

    return <div className='video-container'><YouTube videoId="Zu8MYX5h4x8"  opts={opts} onReady={onPlayerReady} /></div>;
}



export function SponsorUs() {

    return (
        <div className='global'>

            <div className='titleSponsor'>
                { <img className='titleSponsorImg' src={svg} alt=''/>}

                <h1>Le 4l Trophy, c’est quoi?</h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp1'>Le 4L Trophy est un raid étudiant organisé depuis plus de 20 ans au Maroc.
                    Il s'agit d'un défi sportif et humanitaire qui réunit chaque année des milliers d'étudiants
                    venus de toute la France et d'ailleurs. Le but ? Parcourir plus de 6000 kilomètres à bord de 4L,
                    tout en acheminant des fournitures scolaires pour les enfants défavorisés du Maroc.</p>
                <h1>Notre itinéraire </h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp2'>Notre itinéraire pour le 4L Trophy est un véritable parcours du combattant
                    !
                    Nous affronterons les routes les plus difficiles du Maroc, à travers les montagnes,
                    les déserts et les plaines arides. Nous serons confrontés à des défis physiques et mentaux,
                    mais nous sommes prêts à relever le défi !</p>
                { <img className='titleSponsorImg2' src={svg} alt=''/>}
                <h1>Trailer du 4L Trophy</h1>
                <Example />
                <h1 >Vous êtes captivés par notre projet ?</h1>
                <h2 className='reduce'>Aidez-nous à le concrétiser en devenant notre sponsor !</h2>

                <Link to="/contact">
                    <button className='contactButton'>Contact</button>
                </Link>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I think it is related to the height and width defined above but i am unsure, how should i change it to keep the 16 : 9 format

And here is the css :

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");

.titleSponsor {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

.titleSponsor h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    text-align: left;
}

.titleSponsor p {
    padding-left: 5%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.titleSponsorp1 {
    width: 70%;
}

.titleSponsorp2 {
    width: 58%;
}

.titleSponsorImg {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    float: right;
}

.titleSponsorImg2 {
    display: none;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .titleSponsor p {
        width: 80%;
        padding-left: 0%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-size: 12px;

    }
    .titleSponsor h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .titleSponsorImg {
        display: none;
    }
    .titleSponsorImg2 {
        display: block;
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        padding-top: 5%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 1500px) {
    .titleSponsorImg {
        width: 20%;
        height: 20%;
        padding-top: 8%;
        padding-right: 5%;
        float: right;
    }
}
.video-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%; /* Set the width of the iframe */
    height: 100%;
}

.contactButton {
    background-color: #1762A7;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.75rem; /* increase font size */
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem; /* add padding */
    border: none; /* remove border */
    border-radius: 10px; /* add border radius */
    margin: 1.5rem 0; /* add margin */
    width: 100%; /* make button responsive */
    max-width: 15rem; /* set maximum width */
}

.contactButton:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.reduce{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out

Comment: make the player/iframe completely fill the `.video-container` wrapper, don't pass the options to set the width/height, and make the wrapper 16:9 https://playcode.io/1463762 what your code does is make the wrapper 100% width but the player is fixed to 350x640